# How to I redirect to this URL in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is defined some of my routes:

```
Route::get('/success', function () {
     return view('dashboard/dashboard');

  });

 Route::get('/test/{id?}','TestController@parameter' );

 Route::get('/redd','TestController@redirectest' );
```

And here is the controller Method :

```
public function redirectest(){

   return redirect()->route('dashboard.dashboard');
  }
```

Now I have two view named

```
       test.blade.php
       dashboard.blade.php  //In view/dashboard
```

Here is the test.blade.php view just have only a link to redirect to dashboard by controller method.

```
 <html>

 <body>
    <h2><a href="/lvel/public/redd/">Click Me To Redirect to DashBoard</a> 
    </h2>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Now I want to do is simply redirect to the dashboard.blade.php when click on the view link in test.blade.php

But I am getting

```
      Route [dashboard.dashboard] not defined
```

Please help how to define this route for this or what is the solution.
I am new to Laravel.
Thanks.

Comment: really using laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will work sure

```
Route::get('/success', function () {
     return view('dashboard/dashboard');
})->name('dashboard.dashboard');
```

Answer (score 4):

### Route

```
Route::get('/dashboard','TestController@dashBoard')->name('dash_board');
```

### Controller

```
public function dashBoard()
{
   return view('dashboard'); //redirect to view file
}
```

### view

```
<a href="{{ route('dash_board') }}">DashBoard</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to name the route as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('/success', function () {
     return view('dashboard/dashboard');
})->name('dashboard.dashboard');
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the `route()` function you need to give the route a name as follows:

```
Route::get('/success', function () {
    return view('dashboard/dashboard');
})->name('dashboard.dashboard');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this simple explanation

`Route file`

```
Route::get('/dashboard','TestController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
or
Route::get('/dashboard', ['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'TestController@dashboard']);
```

`TestController.php`

```
public function dashboard()
{
   return view('dashboard'); //blade file
}
```

`test.blade.php`

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Click Me To Redirect to DashBoard</a> 
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone already answered (especially @ka_lin) your question with if you would like to redirect you just do a simply named route and redirect to it with:

```
Route::get('/success', function () {
     return view('dashboard/dashboard');
})->name('dashboard.dashboard');
```

To expand further in the answers it is always a good logic to add every action to a `Controller` and you may ask why. Because if you would like to optimize your routes by caching by using the command `php artisan route:cache` you are going to have a problem: this command doesn't work with `Closure based routes` (a.k.a anonymous functions).

By passing the routes to a Controller you can have big advantages that comes with Class based routes.

An example would be:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/dashboard','TestController@dashboard' )->name('dashboard.dashboard');
```

and at the `dashboard` function you can call the view as you are doing in the `Closure`:

```
return view('dashboard/dashboard');
```

Not to mention that everything stays organized in little logical compartments.